# Adding CSS Classes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to know if it is possible to add CSS classes to a parent and its child.

For example:

```
$('#w').html('<ul><li></li></ul>');
$('#w ul').addClass('.filefield-element .filefield-preview');
```

The desired output:

```
$('#w').html() is now:
<ul class="filefield-element"><li class="filefield-preview"></li></ul>
```

Is such a thing possible?
Greetings!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
$('#w ul').addClass('filefield-element').find('li').addClass('filefield-preview');
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just need to select them individually:

```
$('#w ul').addClass('filefield-element').find('li').addClass('filefield-preview');
```

In order, that:

- selects any `<ul>` elements inside the `#w` element;
- adds the `filefield-element` class to them;
- selects any `<li>` elements inside the matched `<ul>` elements;
- adds the `filefield-preview` class to those.